# Historic Flight Landing time

Tags: air-travel

i’m trying to track when British Airways flight BA 2158 from Grenada West Indies landed at Gatwick Airport. The flight was scheduled to depart on 30th December 2017 at 18:20, but departed on 31st December 2017 around 00:30. It flew straight to London Gatwick direct, not stopping at Saint Lucia. It landed at London Gatwick on the 31st December, but am unsure of the time. Many thanks.

Comment: FYI: You can view information about historic flights on flight tracker websites, such as https://flightaware.com/, my favorite.

Answer (score 2):

The plane took off from Grenada at 12:25 AM and landed at Gatwick at 12:00 PM December 31.

Source: https://flightaware.com/live/flight/BAW2158/history/20171231/0200Z/TGPY/EGKK